# Iterating a nested object which is null in angular using ngFor

Tags: angular

I have ngFor iterating through an array of objects,which in turn have object.

```
<div *ngFor="item of items" >
    <div>{{item.item1}}</div>
    <input name="test" [(ngModel)]="{{item.item2.item2a}}" />
</div>
```

Please do not read the syntax,it's typed in mobile.The problem is item2 is null and it errors out item2 is undefined.what should I do this code is just a temporary snippet,I have many columns to display.What should be my approach in solving this?

I checked out and found

`[value]="{{?item.?item2.item2a}}"`

.But I want to modify the record after iterating.Please suggest.

Comment: It would help to see the actual syntax you have instead of asking us not to read what you have typed on mobile. First glance your ? are in the wrong places.

Answer (score 0):

Like Phix stated in the comments, your ? are in the wrong place. This should be your actual code:

```
<input name="test" [(ngModel)]="item?.item2?.item2a" />
```

you can modify your data and display it with `[value]="modifiedData"`